# Правильно ли делать инкрементацию после каждой проверки условия?

Tags: python, if, while

Подскажите, правильно ли, что после каждого if в цикле стоит i += 1 ?

```
from ping3 import ping

urls = ('ya.ru', '8.8.8.8', 'e1.ru', '192.168.0.99', 'google.com', '192.168.1.25', '192.168.1.26', 'ok.ru', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2')

i=0
while i<len(urls):
    ping(urls[i])
    if ping(urls[i]) == None:
        print('None: ', urls[i])
        i += 1
    if ping(urls[i]) == False:
        print('False: ',urls[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        print('OK: ', urls[i])
        i += 1
```

Код работает, но меня смущает, что в справочниках нигде так не пишут, а если так не писать - код работает некорректно. Боюсь, что в большом списке будет какая то ошибка, и в реальной задаче этого будет просто не видно.

Comment: Это не неправильно, это некрасиво, я бы сказал - нарушает принцип программирования DRY - do not repeat yourself. вынесите i+=1 в основной цикл и все.

Comment: Код не работает, к сожалению. Он и падает и ошибается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Выход за границу списка

Функция `ping` всегда возвращает `None`, один адрес в списке. Если в списке адресов последний адрес не ответит, скрипт упадет:

```
def ping(url):
    return None

urls = ('a', )

i=0
while i<len(urls):
    ping(urls[i])
    if ping(urls[i]) == None:
        print('None: ', urls[i])
        i += 1
    if ping(urls[i]) == False:
        print('False: ',urls[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        print('OK: ', urls[i])
        i += 1
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> None:  a
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py", line 12, in <module>
>     if ping(urls[i]) == False:
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
> ```

### Ошибочный ответ

Если в списке адресов два адреса подряд не ответят, то для второго адреса код напечатает "OK". Функция `ping` всегда возвращает `None`, два адреса в списке. Я ожидаю что ответом будет

> ```
> None:  a
> None:  b
> ```

Запускаем:

```
def ping(url):
    return None


urls = ('a', 'b')

i=0
while i<len(urls):
    ping(urls[i])
    if ping(urls[i]) == None:
        print('None: ', urls[i])
        i += 1
    if ping(urls[i]) == False:
        print('False: ',urls[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        print('OK: ', urls[i])
        i += 1
```

Для второго адреса печатается "OK":

> ```
> None:  a
> OK:  b
> ```

### Рабочий вариант

```
for url in urls:
    r = ping(url)
    v = 'OK'
    if r is None:
        v = 'None'
    if r is False:
        v = 'False'
    print(f'{v}: {url}')
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, почему не работает, если в выводе все достоверно работает, но то что некрасиво - я согласен. >>> ping('example.com')  # Returns delay in seconds.
0.215697261510079666  # `0.0` returned means the delay is lower than the precision of `time.time()`.

>>> ping('not.exist.com')  # If host unknown (cannot resolve), returns False.
False

>>> ping("224.0.0.0")  # If timed out (no reply), returns None.
None

Comment: Если в вашем списке два домена подряд не ответят, то для второго домена вы получите 'OK'.

Comment: Если в вашем списке не ответит последний домен, скрипт упадет.

Comment: Спасибо, Станислав, в этом и была загвоздка, скрипт постоянно падал, когда я писал его на работе. Сейчас проверил с вашим вариантом - все работает как нужно, и скрипт не выдает ошибку. Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 2):

Так неправильно. См. ответ @StanislavVolodarskiy

Вот так лучше :

```
else:
    print('OK: ', urls[i])
i += 1
```

Остальные `i += 1` убрать.

Ещё лучше, поскольку идёт итерация по списку, использовать проход по списку:

```
for url in urls:
    ping(url)
    if ping(url) == None:
        print('None: ', url)
    if ping(url) == False:
        print('False: ',url)
    else:
        print('OK: ', url)
```

Плюс, здесь каждый адрес пингуется три раза, из которых один вообще бесполезно. Вот это уже плохо, потому что результаты могут оказаться разными. Правильно примерно так:

```
for url in urls:
    result = ping(url)
    if result == None:
        print('None: ', url)
    if result == False:
        print('False: ',url)
    else:
        print('OK: ', url)
```

Comment: Код ТС делает ошибки, которые не трудно описать. Это не может быть "не неправильно".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy эти ошибки относятся к циклу?

Comment: Да, относятся к циклу.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное описание, Эникейщик! Код стал работать намного быстрей и тоже выдает верную информацию!

Answer (score 0):

так, по идее, должно работать:

```
for url in urls:
    print(f'OK: {url}' if (r:=ping(url)) else f'{r}: {url}')
```